# Using WITH..AS with UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I cant make the following bit of a Stored proc compile although the query by itself runs fine:

```
UPDATE t  
         SET   
            requestType= sp.requestType
      FROM #tempComp  AS t,
      (
          WITH CT AS
            (
                ........            )
            SELECT x, y, z
            FROM CT WHERE ab = 1
        )   AS sp  
      WHERE t.Id = sp.Id
```

Whats the correct way to organize this?

Comment: You can put the common table expression "on top of" the `UPDATE` e.g. `WITH CT AS ( ... ) UPDATE ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whats the correct way to organize this?

According to [the manual](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx), the CTE comes first.

```
[ WITH <common_table_expression> [...n] ]
UPDATE ...
```

In your case:

```
WITH CT AS
(
   ........
)
UPDATE t  
SET requestType = sp.requestType
FROM #tempComp AS t,
     ( SELECT x, y, z
       FROM CT
       WHERE ab = 1 ) AS sp  
WHERE t.Id = sp.Id
```